# How to use a variable from one function in the next function after returned

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

Can not pass the encoded information to the the second function.
I know that when the variable is returned that the data is basically None.
But I'm looking for a work around.

```
string = 'WWWWBBWWWWBWWWBBBBWWWWWWBBWWWWW'

# Encoding algroithm.
def runLengthEncoding(data):
    runCount = 0
    i = 0
    data = data + '5'
    encoded = ''
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == data[j]:
            runCount += 1
        else:
             encoded += str(runCount)+ '' + data[i]
             i = j
             runCount = 1
    return encoded

# Decoding algorithm.
def runLengthDecoding(encoded):
    k = 0
    decoded = ''
    for l in range(len(encoded), 2):
        if encoded[k]:
           if encoded[l]:
              decoded += int(encoded[k]) * encoded[l]
              k += 2
    return decoded

print('\t\t\t***Run Length Encoding***\n')
print('Uncompressed:', string)
print('Encoded:  ', runLengthEncoding(string))
print('\n\t\t\t***Run Length Decoding***\n')
print('Encoded:  ', runLengthEncoding(string))
# Can't use the return value.
print('Decoded:  ', runLengthDecoding(runLengthEncoding(string)))
```

Comment: The second argument to `range` does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that you can't use the return value, the problem is that your Decoding function doesn't actually add anything to your string and just returns "". Replace your decoding function with this bug free version and it will work:

```
def runLengthDecoding(encoded):
    decoded = ''
    for i in range(0, len(encoded), 2):
        decoded += int(encoded[i])*encoded[i+1]
    return decoded
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It did work as a standalone function so I thought it would work combined with the encoding function.

Comment: If the solution solved your problem please mark it as accepted

Comment: I am happy to help :)

Comment: Now I know why it worked as a standalone function I forgot to add the '1' in for l in range(1, len(encoded), 2):  But I'm glad I asked, because your code is optimized.